# How to port-foward without router acces

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I am using a Nokia modem/router provided by my isp. When I try to access the router page it is unavailable locked away by the isp. I want to forward some Tcp/Ucp ports to allow my Minecraft and website server to be open to the outside and not on the LAN network only.
Is there any work-around to this?

Answer (score 0):

If your ISP will allow you to have your own router, you might be able to have them install a modem without the builtin router. If not, there's no way around such a severely restricted modem/router combination. They usually do that for that very reason. They do not want people opening/forwarding ports to their network.

You MIGHT be able to do a Google or DuckDuckGo.com search to see if someone has posted the ISPs password for that modem/router. But you'll probably be violating their terms of service and depending on your ISP, they could refuse you any service. Or they might periodically refresh the modem/router settings to their preferred settings.

Comment: There is no router page when I enter the IP address, it says This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 0):

You can ask ISP to set up their modem/router in the bridge mode which will disable NAT on their router and you will be able to configure your router as the main gateway and will allow you to setup port forwarding.  How do you know that nokia actually does NATing and blocks all the ports.  Usually you should be able to port forward on your router and traffic will be routed correctly

Comment: Well im not sure if it is the isp or what but I've never seen a Nokia router like tis

Comment: If you can post the router model info.

Comment: Its screwed up on a bracket that I cant acces

Comment: https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.mx/MLM-641762600-modem-telmex-fibra-optica-nokia-nuevo-_JM that's the router itself it looks very sketchy

Comment: Minus the Telmex logos that it

Comment: Have you seen this doc https://downloads.telmex.com/pdf/guiapersonalizaturedONT.pdf  which IP address are you entering to try to login to the router?

Comment: I'm using the default gateway up address that appears in my windows settings, thanks for actually reply by the way

Comment: are you connecting wired or wireless?  Can you try entering your subnet .254 as suggested in the doc.  Which would be weird but worth a try. You can also scan the network and see if there any other IPs are you used and do a port scan on that IP.  They might have webserver running on a different port.

Comment: I'll try thank you

Comment: I tried doing hooking up a router to the main router as an extender and I am getting access to the router page via thew extender using an ethernet connection to my laptop. My computer is connected via tethering as it is very far away from the main router and I don't have a long cable to extend it